# Deep link to specific message in thread (when conversation threading is enabled)

Tags: gmail-api

Is there any documentation or has anyone figured out how to deep link a specific thread in conversation view?

The toolbar shows [this](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/1499fca2ad49d88a) for a random message in a thread, but note it doesn't update when you choose another message in that thread so that's no help

If you do a search it will drill down to the message you want, but its using search terms which doesn't fit my use case. With the API I want to be able to link to to the specific message that had an attachment.  For example, I can't build some series of search terms:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/%22Your+terms%2C+here%22/1499fca2ad49d88a

However I've found if you turn threading off you obviously get a different URL for each email. I don't know any heathens who don't use threading though, so that's not a solution.

Anyone?

Bonus points if instead of message id you can index on say attachment id or something else exclusive to the new API.

Answer (score 0):

Via Ticket Overflow:

> If you are just using the Gmail API you can use the filter parameter
>   of the 'list' method for messages [1] (as opposed to threads), and
>   then do a 'get' [2] on the message you want. See also [3] for details
>   on searching messages.
>
> Constructing a direct link to a message in the Gmail UI is a different
>   story though. It doesn't work simply due to how the UI itself is
>   designed. You can test this without the API:
>
> 1) You can get a link to an individual message in a thread if you
>   first disable conversation view and do a search. 2) Copy the link and
>   then re-enable conversation view. 3) Paste that link back to link to
>   the message. You will see that the UI still only links to the thread,
>   and doesn't zero in on the specific message.
>
> However, you can 'trick' the UI into displaying the exact message in a
>   thread by using a search, as
>   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#search// will show
>   the search result for thread  and will zero in on the message that
>   matched . You can build the URL by first using the API to
>   'list' and 'get' the message you want to link to, and then build the
>   search query based on the exact text in the message.
>
> The above example probably isn't foolproof and I would not recommend
>   using it in production, however it is there as an example. I would
>   still recommend using the API to display messages in your own
>   interface.